# Nested ssh With Start Commands and Heredoc

Tags: ssh

I have a situation that isn't ideal as far as security and work is concerned, but the idea is that I have to connect to a server via another, I can't store keys anywhere and I have to do varying stuff in the inner shell. So after some tinkering I got this to work:

```
sshpass -p"mypass1" ssh mxd 'sshpass -p"mypass2" ssh -t 10.10.10.10 "cd /path/to/work; /bin/bash -i"'
```

So the `cd` is done and I can type and execute commands in the inner shell.

As this isn't really readable I tried to improve it with heredoc:

```
sshpass -p"mypass1" ssh mxd bash <<EOF1
sshpass -p"mypass2" ssh -t 10.10.10.10 bash <<EOF2
cd /path/to/work
/bin/bash -i
EOF2
EOF1
```

The thing is that it performs the `cd` (the prompt says so), but then immediately exits both ssh. The goal is that equally to the first snippet I can enter commands in the inner shell. What am I missing here?

Comment: Doesn't the jump host functionality built into open ssh provide this, but much easier and securely?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I need to send the password through, so as far as I understood jump hosts they are no option for that.

Comment: You misunderstood that, then. In a ssh jump host, that is unproblematic.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not sure what I should do with your post. If you know how I can squeeze a password into a jump host, feel free to tell me.